# How should the mat-slider be used inside a form configured with formGroup? Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-slider

I have created a form that has inputs of text type and a mat-slider to get a numeric value

```
// TS
this.consumptionForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      dailyConsumption: ['', Validators.required],
      cost: [20, Validators.required],
    });

// HTML
<form #form="ngForm" [formGroup]="consumptionForm" novalidate>
     <label>Cost</label>
     <mat-slider formControlName="cost" [min]="10" [max]="1000" >
                </mat-slider>


   <div>
           <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="true">
              <mat-label>Daily Consumption</mat-label>
               <input matInput formControlName="dailyConsumption"/>
           </mat-form-field>
        </div>
 </form>
```

I want the mat-slider to work in conjunction with the rest of the form, and if it is not possible to know which approach is used to use it.

I see that the formControlName is not working

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit old ... Anyway, I used **[(value)]="consumptionForm.value.cost"** to resolve the same issue, instead of **formControlName="cost"**

```
    <mat-slider [min]="10" [max]="1000" [(value)]="consumptionForm.value.cost"></mat-slider>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Angular Material v16, the `formControlName` for the slider belongs on the slider's `matSliderThumb` `input` element:

```
<mat-slider>
  <input formControlName="cost" #mySlider>
</mat-slider>
```

and `cost` is updated by the slider automatically, as is the `mySlider.value` template variable.